Interpolation constant on triangles
There are quite a few references regarding the estimation for the interpolation error for the piece-wise affine finite elements. I find one particular estimate interesting (and useful in my case), however, I can't find a proof for it.
The estimate in question is
$$ |u-I_K(u)|\leq C(K)|u|_{H^2}$$
where $K$ is a triangle, $I_K(u)$ is the affine function taking the same values as $u$ at the vertices of $K$ and
$$ C(K) = \sqrt{\frac{A^2B^2C^2}{16S^2} - \frac{A^2+B^2+C^2}{30}-\frac{S^2}{5}\left(\frac{1}{A^2}+\frac{1}{B^2}+\frac{1}{C^2}\right)},$$
where $A,B,C$ are the sides of the triangle and $S$ is its area.
In this paper also available on arxiv the above inequality due to Kobayashi's is mentioned as a "Theorem", i.e. as an admitted result. The reference for the proof is the following article, where it seems that only numerical validations are given (even though they seem to be given using interval arithmetics, nevertheless, the details regarding the computations are unknown). Moreover, a reference in Japanese is given for the full argument.
Therefore my question:

Is this result, with the constant provided, known and admitted in the literature? Has anyone proved it using analytical tools?


Reading more closely Kobayashi's paper it seems that a bound is proved between $C(K)$ and the first (discrete) eigenvalue of a Morley eigenvalue problem. The bounds in the paper are obtained for a fixed family of triangles using this estimate on a rather coarse mesh and using interval arithmetics to certify the bounds on the given eigenvalues.

I haven't personally seen this upper bound before. If this claim is true, it could improve some results in $h$-optimal preconditioning of PDEs.

I think you should check the list of publications by Carsten Carstensen from the 1990s and 2000s.

@WolfgangBangerth: Thanks. That's quite a list of publications. I will take a look.
